# Font Awesome Icons not schowing correctly on Opera and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts, icons, opera

I have issue with font awesome icons on my website: www.theguardiandog.com

On Firefox icons show correctly, but on Opera and Chrome they move at the top of the circle.

1. On Firefox: http://prntscr.com/h29hpo
2. On Opera and Chrome: http://prntscr.com/h29hcm

I can't found any information about this issue :/

Comment: Someone, something?